# Rx IObservable - return first IObservable stream to get a value

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I am creating two (or more) `IObservable<T>`s of all the same T.  They have been generated from `Task<IEnumerable<T>>` of which one can come back quicker than the others.  All I care about is the `IObservable` which returns the first value - this is the one that I use from then on.

I remember attending a Jon Skeet presentation in Cambridge where he did exactly this using the TPL in a very neat way but I can't remember how!  Ideally I'd get a method something like this:

```
IObservable<T> PickFastestObservable<T>(IEnumerable<IObservable<T>> slowObservables);
```

But if I had to do it on the tasks directly, I could probably work something out.

I'm struggling to get something up myself that I'm confident with.

Cheers,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want [Observable.Amb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229115%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) e.g.

```
IObservable<T> fastest = slowObservables.Amb();
```

Comment: Does this unsubscribe from the other IObservables (they are hot observables), once the first value has come through?

Comment: @jamespconnor - The documentation doesn't give much detail, but I would certainly expect it to release its subscriptions when it has a value.

Comment: Looking at the source under reflector it does indeed dispose of the unnecessary subscriptions.